# How do I perform a linear search over this inventory array then the index of the matching item if it is found, -1 if it is not found?

Tags: c

```
Does my method look correct? I have a function called:
```

> int searchInventory(const struct Item items[], const int sku_item,
>   const int size)

This function receives the address of an array of type Item (items[]), an integer for the sku number of the desired item, and an integer size representing the size of the array. I'm not sure if I used the flags correctly. Through the array I have to search for an item with the desired sku number and **return** the index of the matching item if it is found. **If not found I have to return -1**. New to this site, so I am not sure I have given all the needed info for you guys to help me. If you understand at all, please advise me.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (sku_item == items[i]._sku)

        return i;
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: `return -1;` move to after for-loop. (and delete else-block)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (sku_item == items[i]._sku) {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
```

You need to iterate over the whole array before declaring the item is not found. So move `return -1` outside of the loop.